# Magento 2: How to block or disable invoice email if payment method is "Invoice" or "Bank transfer"?

Tags: magento2

[Magento 2 send order & invoice email manually](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/232562/24411)

This may related but it doesn't solve my problem. Any ideas or specific approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Plugin;

class CheckOrderTypeAndSendEmail
{
 
    public function aroundSave(\Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\EmailSender $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        // write your logic here to find what kind of payment method was used
        if ($this->validPayment($subject->getOrder())) {
            return $proceed(); // it goes ahead and sends email
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

http://www.rosenborgsolutions.com/how-to-extend-magento-part-1.php